# GIT FLOW Como manter arquivos na branch master e na develop e o release não faça o merge apagando?

Tags: git, git-flow

Tenho 3 arquivos de formato .yml que preciso que eles sempre estejam na branch master porque são eles que executam a publicação automatica do sistema, mas esses arquivos não podem estar na branch develop.

Então fui e apaguei eles da branch develop mas toda vez que gero um novo release, quando o merge acontece ele apaga esses arquivos da branch master.

Como faço para que isso não aconteça?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Os arquivos são apagados pois como deixam de exitir na branch de desenvolvimento, quando você faz o merge, ele entende que você quer apagar eles também, é como o git funciona. Seria possível também o uso do git lfs e bloquear o arquivo para edição.

Mas esses arquivos não deveriam ser o problema do seu processo de deploy, neste caso:

- O seu processo de integração contínua deve eliminá-los do artefato a ser publicado, ou seja, não coloque eles no artefato que será gerado nesse processo, caso seja rodado na branch de dev.
- O arquivo não pode estar na dev por causa de dados sensíveis, como senha de BD? Nesse caso é preciso utilizar um cofre ou variáveis de ambiente, no CI que você está utilizando, Jenkins, Azure DevOps ou Github Actions; e no lugar do dado fica um token, quando o rodar o processo de CI, esse token é substituído pelo dado sensível, assim, o desenvolvedor não tem acesso a eles.

Comment: Na verdade são esses aquivos yml que fazem com que o deploy seja inicializado em produção(rode o pipeline,etc) por isso a necessidade deles existirem na master, se mantenho eles na dev toda vez que subir um commit na dev ele jogará pra produção também.

Comment: O seu pipeline deve ser responsável por levar para produção somente os arquivos necessários, isso inclui um processo de montar o artefato gerado, pegando somente os arquivos para o deploy.

Você está usando qual ferramenta como pipeline? Qual linguagem?

Comment: Estou usando php com codedeploy da aws mais o pipeline do bitbucket.

Comment: Durante o processo do pipeline no Bitbucket apaga os arquivos que você não precisa e gera o artefato limpo para o Code Deploy, entendeu?

Comment: Consegui resolver, no bitbucket-pipelines.yml adiciona a configuração que gera o deploy apenas para a branch master, sendo assim o arquivo pode estar em todas as outras branches mas quando o push for feito na master ai sim ele gera o deploy.